# The problem with redux not working on button click

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am new to Redux and was learning how to use it with React. Basically, I did everything correctlyin terms of setting up Redux with react app but when I click on  button increment I expect displaying counter to increment by one. But when I do that nothing happens and, certainly, I have checked dispatch and action being sent but basically all is ok. Thus I truly need your help guys here is the code I am using:

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import registerServiceWorker from "./registerServiceWorker";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import reducer from "./store/reducer";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

const store = createStore(reducer);
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
registerServiceWorker();
```

reducer.js

```
const initialState = {
  counter: 0
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  if (action.type === "INCREMENT") {
    return { counter: state.counter + 1 };
  }

  return state;
};

export default reducer;
```

counter.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import CounterControl from "../../components/CounterControl/CounterControl";
import CounterOutput from "../../components/CounterOutput/CounterOutput";

class Counter extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <CounterOutput value={this.props.ctr} />
        <CounterControl
          label="Increment"
          clicked={() => this.props.onIncrement}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { ctr: state.counter };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onIncrement: () => dispatch({ type: "INCREMENT" })
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Counter);
```

Comment: I don't see countercontrol but you are not executing the onIncrement function: `clicked={() => this.props.onIncrement()}` was missing `()`. Also no need to re create the function again: `clicked={this.props.onIncrement}` should work. Counter does not need to be a class, you can define it as function: `const Couner = ({onIncrement,ctr})=>(<div>,,,clicked={onIncrement})`

Comment: Also have a look at [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) your CounterContainer (incorrectly called Counter and incorrectly returning jsx) is assuming to know the path to where it's props can be found `state.counter`. Also here is no memoization happening so even if `state.counter` didn't change your Counter will re render.

Comment: @HMR, thank you for your kind comments, you mean since all we have is store, we can work solely with function containers without class containers Right? Also, do you use immutable.js is it best practice?

Comment: Immutablejs is not needed in my opinion since we have spread: `newState = {...oldState, newValue}`. The Counter does not need to be a class because the only method it has is render, there is no code there that needs it to be a class.

Comment: @HMR, ok I changed clicked={() => this.props.onIncrement} to clicked={() => this.props.onIncrement()} and it works. But wait a second, shouldn't clicked={() => this.props.onIncrement()} run the code right away even if I do not click a button?

Comment: You should do `clicked={this.props.onIncrement}` as suggested before and you'll not create a new function on every render. What `const click = ()=>fn()` does is assign a function to `click` (the `()=>` part and if you call click it'll call fn: `fn()`. Therefor you may as well do: `const click=fn`. In both cases what happens when we do `click()` is `fn()`

Comment: @HMR, oh my gosh so hard to be beginner :D, ok, if I change to clicked={this.props.onIncrement} nothing happens if I click on button why?. Gosh a bit confused

Comment: You don't get errors?

Comment: @HMR, nope I do not get any errors

Answer (score 0):

Did you register your reducer with store?

If not, please do that.

I believe this thing should not return string:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { ctr: state.counter };
};
```

Comment: hi Vishal thank you for your kind answer, do you think the issue is somewhere here const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { ctr: state.counter };
}; ??

Comment: @Dickens I think you should register your reducer with store first. Then you will be able to access it here,